# Where to get frame size of custom UIView in its subclass

Tags: swift, uiview, ios8, frame

When does the correct frame size of the UIView is calculated when I add my custom UIView by using storyboard? 
I can't get correct frame size in **UIView's** `init(frame: CGRect)` or `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` or `awakeFromNib()`. I get the correct size in `override func layoutSubviews()` but this time the view is not added to the view controller's view.

**Edit:**
I want to do this in the UIView subclass because I add a `CAGradientLayer` layer (which has same size with my view) to my custom `UIView`. There must be a better way than setting up the view in `UIViewController`s `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

There are two vertical constraints (trailing and leading space to superview) that adjust the width of my custom view. But the width is 600 in the mentioned methods, not the screen width.

Comment: `I get the correct size in override func layoutSubviews() but this time the view is not added to the view controller's view.` Why?

Comment: I have no idea. The question is about this :) It does not appear.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
```

This is called on the viewController after the view hierarchy is in place and the geometry is set up.

It is usually the best place to arrange geometry-dependent viewController code, and is called just before transition animations are run.

It is followed by a call to `viewDidAppear` which is called after transition animations have completed.

**update**

as you want to set this directly in a custom view (rather than in the viewController)  the appropriate UIView function to override is `layoutSubviews`. Be sure to call `super.layoutSubviews()` in the override.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    //self.frame will be correct here
}
```

This will be called after the viewController's `viewWillAppear` and before `viewDidAppear`

**update 2: collectionView cells**
Collection view cells get their frame data from the collectionview's layout. When a cell needs to know it's geometry, you can override `applyLayoutAttributes`

```
func applyLayoutAttributes(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes!)
```

One of the default layoutAttributes is the frame property. See also my comment below on how to extract the frame directly from collectionView.layout.

Comment: `I want to do this in the UIView subclass`

Comment: `I get the correct size in override func layoutSubviews() but this time the view is not added to the view controller's view` or at least I can't see it

Comment: `super.layoutSubviews()` was forgotten I think. Or I did something else wrong before. Damn, that was an easy bounty :)

Comment: I don't want to let you go with this easy bounty :) Similar question: Is there any way to get the correct size of a collectionViewCell in `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) `

Comment: @osrl - a quick (untested) answer would be to ask the collection view's layout. Something like `[collectionView.layout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame` might do the trick. Thanks for the bounty!  //swift : `collectionView.layout.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath).frame`

Comment: sorry but me again @foundry . `layoutSubviews` doesn't give me the correct size of the `CollectionViewCell` in `CollectionViewCell`s subclass. And I didn't forgot the `super` call this time :) Where should I get correct frame?

Comment: @osrl - see my previous reply. You can get the frame from the collection view's layout. Alternatively, overriding `layoutsubviews` on a _subview_ of the cell subclass might work.

Comment: Yes you were right about it. `collectionView.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath).frame` How do I do it in the subclass?

Comment: sorry but no luck. here it is as a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940635/how-to-get-the-correct-frame-of-uicollectionviewcell-in-its-subclass

Answer (score 1):

Since `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is getting called multiple times, I'd recommend using the `viewDidAppear()` delegate.

`viewDidLoad()` is called before any frame was set.

`viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called during frame sizing and will be called multiple times with different frame sizes (usually frameZero before a frame is calculated).

`viewDidAppear()` All frames are set.

Comment: Sorry, I added missing infromation

Answer (score 0):

You should have an IBOutlet to your UIView and in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method, get the size by `yourViewOutlet.frame.size`.

Comment: Sorry, I added missing infromation