# How to get the correct frame of UICollectionViewCell in it's subclass

Tags: swift, ios8, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` and I set it's cellSize in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    let cellWidth = self.view.frame.width / 2
    self.collectionViewFlowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: 100)`
```

I try to add a gradient layer to my custom `UICollectionViewCell`. But the frame size is the one I set from storyboard. I can't get the correct, calculated frame size in my `UICollectionViewCell` subclass's `layoutSubviews` method.

How am I going to get the correct frame size?

Comment: What have you tried and how is the size wrong (i.e. what is it and what did you expect it to be)?

Comment: I get the size `I set from storyboard` I expect it to be `CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: 100)` I tried overriding `layoutSubviews` and `applyLayoutAttributes`

Comment: What did you do in the overrides, show that code. Did it make any difference?

Comment: `let backgroundLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        backgroundLayer.colors = colors
        backgroundLayer.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)       
        self.layer.insertSublayer(backgroundLayer, atIndex: 100)`

Comment: you insert a new layer on each call to `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: i just tried it to see if I could get the correct frame.

Comment: Did you try logging what the frame is and resizing the subview?

Comment: Yes I tried logging. What do you mean with resizing the subview?

Comment: Set the frame of the sublayer, to the size of the super layer.