# Get frame size in updateConstraint function of Custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, frame, cgrect

I'm setting constraints for views (`UILabel`, `UIImageView`) in custom `UIView` inside `UpdateConstraint` functions like below. As seen, I'm getting views' height and use it inside auto layout. I know I can get frame size in `layoutSubviews` function. If I call `updateConstraint()` function inside `layoutSubViews` , everything works fine but I don't know If It is the best approach.

In addition when I try to set frame in `layoutSubViews()` with `label.frame = CGRect..` (without auto layout) nothing happens and I can't see custom views inside superview.

```
    override func updateConstraints() {
    logoImage.anchor(self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: self.frame.height / 2, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    label.anchor(self.logoImage.bottomAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: self.rightAnchor, topConstant: 12, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    super.updateConstraints()

}
override func layoutSubviews() {
    print(self.frame.height)
    updateConstraints()
}
```

I searched below posts but can't find any solution;

[Where to get frame size of custom UIView in its subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758973/where-to-get-frame-size-of-custom-uiview-in-its-subclass)

[Subview of Custom UIView has wrong x frame position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006395/subview-of-custom-uiview-has-wrong-x-frame-position)

Answer (score 0):

No need to handle that in `layoutSubviews` if your current constraint create extension sets `isActive = true` then it will have the correct frame

//

correct way of creating a customView

```
class CustomView : UIView {

    var imageV = UIImageView()

    var once = true

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedLayout()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedLayout()
    }
    func sharedLayout() {

       // set constraints here

        self.addSubview(imageV)

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {

        if once {

            self.imageV.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            self.imageV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            self.imageV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            self.imageV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
            self.imageV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

            once = false

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer, can you please give more detail? It is not working If I don't call updateConstraints inside layoutSubViews.

Comment: My problem is that I'm using views frame in constraint like  self.imageV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, MULTIPILIER: SELF.FRAME.HEIGHT / 2).isActive

Comment: if this your case then no need to override **updateConstraints** make it a usual function and call it once from **layoutSubviews** as **layoutSubviews**  is called multiple times

Comment: Hmm then do I need to move my auto layout code inside layoutSubviews? from updateConstraint?